# AWS Step Function: custom end state for choices

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a choice state like below:

```
"ChoiceStateX": {
  "Type": "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Not": {
        "Variable": "$.type",
        "StringEquals": "Private"
      },
      "Next": "Public"
    },
    {
      "Variable": "$.value",
      "NumericEquals": 0,
      "Next": "MyEndState"  // can I do something like this? 
    },
}
```

For the state with $.value == 0, I need to end the step function, because `Choices` does NOT support `End: true`, I need explicitly to have something like `MyEndState`.

So how should I define `MyEndState` inside the step function? Is there a such way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I do in that case is add a `PassState` that has `End: true`, and send the `Next` of the `ChoiceState` to that state.

Comment: Check out the Pass documentation for the full structure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html

Answer (score 3):

A state of `"Type": "Succeed"` seems specifically designed for this purpose.

[The AWS documentation of the `Succeed` state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-succeed-state.html) explains that it is a useful target for **Choice** state branches that don't do anything but stop the execution (they are terminal states, they have no `Next` field, and don't need an `End` field).

So I would just add:

```
"SuccessState": {
  "Type": "Succeed"
}
```

And (instead of `MyEndState`) point that Choice's `"Next"` to `"SuccessState"`.